# Magento 2: Get sub-category URLs & limit amount fetched

Tags: magento2, php

I'm having a hard time being able to get the sub-category URLs for my navigator in my template.

**UPDATE:**

I've figured out my main issue, but now I'm wondering how can I limit the amount of sub-categories/child-nodes? I'd like to fetch a max of 3.

**Block Code:**

```
protected $_categoryHelper;
protected $categoryFlatConfig;
protected $topMenu;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu)
{
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
    $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Return categories helper
 */
public function getCategoryHelper()
{
    return $this->_categoryHelper;
}

/**
 * Retrieve current store categories
 *
 * @param bool|string $sorted
 * @param bool $asCollection
 * @param bool $toLoad
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
 */
public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
{
    return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
}

/**
 * Retrieve child store categories
 *
 */
public function getChildCategories($category)
{
    if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
        $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
    } else {
        $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
    }
    return $subcategories;
}
```

**Template Code:**

```
<?php
$categorys = $this->getStoreCategories(false, false, true);
foreach($categorys as $category) 
{
    echo '                  
    <li class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">'.$category->getName().'</li>';
            foreach($this->getChildCategories($category) as $childrenCategory) 
            {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$childrenCategory->getUrl().'">'.$childrenCategory->getName().'</a></li>';
            }

            echo '
            <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>';
}
?>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.. Got it, just had to use the `getCategoryHelper()` function..

Just had to simply reference the `$categoryHelper` and then use `getCategoryUrl()` instead.

```
<?php
$categorys = $this->getStoreCategories(false, false, true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();

foreach($categorys as $category) 
{
    echo '                  
    <li class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">'.$category->getName().'</li>';
            foreach($this->getChildCategories($category) as $childrenCategory) 
            {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory).'">'.$childrenCategory->getName().'</a></li>';
            }

            echo '
            <li><a href="'.$categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category).'">View All</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps someone else too.